# Huawei Dynamic Tag Manager, Click Event Does Not Respond

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I implemented Huawei DTM to my project,

with dependency :

```
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:dtm-api:5.0.0.301'
```

I added an event to the layout like below, however when I click to the item there is no Response.

Layout Code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onReport"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

and my onReport function:

```
public void onReport(View view) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("Price", 9.99);
    bundle.putDouble("Money", 9.99);
    if (instance != null) {
        instance.onEvent("Purchase", bundle);
    }
}
```

Any idea which part I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event reporting on your sub-layout, it will not work on main layout.

In next releases of the DTM this problem will be solved.